# Calendar Overlay Setting in SharePoint 2010 issue

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

Is it possible to set **dynamic URL** in Calendar overlay settings -> Web Url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can not set dynamic url in overlay settings

Answer (score 0):

You should try this link for your problem.

http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2011/06/programmatically-setting-sharepoint-2010-calendar-overlays/